# Serial downvoting

Tags: discussion, down-votes, serial-voting

Yesterday I got 9 downvoting. And the downvoting was done within 2 minutes, from 14:29 to 14:30 (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/16158/paul?tab=reputation)). Some of the answers received downvoting have received more than 10 upvotes (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165226/example-of-an-infinite-sequence-of-irrational-numbers-converging-to-a-rational-n/165231#165231), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95562/how-to-calculate-z4-frac1z4-if-z2-z-1-0/95566#95566), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96646/whats-the-connection-between-derivatives-and-boundaries/96659#96659)). It seems to me that  someone is just downvoting to downvote. I wonder if I can do anything to reverse the downvotes.

Comment: In the event of serial downvoting, the votes will be reset within the next day usually. This is not an uncommon occurrence. It has happened to me at least on three or four occasions. I think moderators are notified in the event of serial downvoting and they usually contact the user to tell them to cut it out. If they don't stop, they get suspended and/or banned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system should recognize this, and will revert them in the next reputation recalculation. If this doesn't happen (it should!), we can look at it with more care. In general, I would recommend you wait for the reputation recalculation even before making a meta post about it.

Comment: What happens if serial downvoting is organized by a group in Chat, and comes from several people?

Comment: @AndréNicolas If you have strong suspicion as to who that people be, you can always talk with a community manager. Of course, assuming the downvoting is serial and/or spiteful.