# Serial down-voting

Tags: discussion, specific-question, serial-voting

I answered three question a while back, and today when I logged-in I see they were all voted down in chronological order. In fact one of my answers was even accepted by OP.

Refer to these links:

[proof that $A \triangle (B \triangle C) = (A \triangle B) \triangle C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3012766/proof-that-a-triangle-b-triangle-c-a-triangle-b-triangle-c/3012826#3012826)

[what is the cardinality of $\{n^{1/k}: n, k\in \mathbb{N}\}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3017925/what-is-the-cardinality-of-n1-k-n-k-in-mathbbn/3017951#3017951)

[Prove that if $T:U \to V$ is an isomorphism and $\dim_F (V)=n\in \mathbb{N}$, show that $\dim_F(U)=n\in \mathbb{N}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3019423/prove-that-if-tu-to-v-is-an-isomorphism-and-dim-f-v-n-in-mathbbn-sh/3019540#3019540)

Were my answers deficient? As far as I know, they are all rigorous. Are there criteria for downvoting answers, like there are for questions? Were my answers not on par with the criteria?

Regards!

Comment: No. Yes there is a criteria, if the answer is not useful then you should downvote,though this not your case because obviously your answers are fine, useful an even one accepted :) so don't worry about it..

Comment: @Isah Thanks for the assurance! XD as long as the answers are correct I am happy. Regards.

Comment: Allow me a nitpick: "criterion" is the singular form of "criteria." You can say "Is there a criterion?" or "Are there criteria?"

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip meh, I had a C in english. Don't criticize my english. Jk. Lol.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip whichever seems to fit the question, I guess.

Comment: See also: [(1)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9179/), [(2)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19506/), and [(3)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25807/).  Other related topics can be found by [searching](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=serial+downvoting).

Comment: I briefly looked at the second of the linked answers. There were significant issues (symbols that made no sense as written, unexplained notation and so on). Meaning: even if superficially an answer appears correct, it may well still be lacking in quality, which may attract downvotes.

Comment: In the future, when you notice you've received a handful or more of downvotes in a very short period of time, the best course of action is to flag *one* of the affected posts, indicating the flag is for *moderator attention*, and explain the recent influx of downvotes on $n$ of your questions.  You can also check out the moderator's chat room and talk with a mod their, but flagging will be more expedient.  The mod's then can view your reputation top in your profile to find the other occurrences.  Please do not post to meta.math.se every time you think you're a the victim of serial voting.

Comment: I now looked also at the third of your linked answers, and the whole beginning of it is wrong as well.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo That is not my answer, that was Op's proof which i told him was wrong.

Comment: @amWhy Ok, thanks for that!

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo My proof starts at the very end.

Comment: @Bertrand Hehe. Sure.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo dude, did you even read my answer? The first part is just telling Op why their proof is wrong.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo so you think $\vec u\in \{\alpha \vec u_1+\alpha \vec u_2+...+\alpha \vec u_n\}$, when $\vec u=text{span}\{...\}$. Do you think that is correct?

Comment: @Bertrand And that is probably why that answer was downvoted.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I don't get it, what is the point of this comment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone is likely downvoting answers to low-quality questions. Often, even if the answer is well-written, people will downvote to discourage answering questions that should be closed instead of answered.

As an example, your second linked question contains no signs of any effort by the poster. This should be closed for lack of context. By answering questions like this, you are encouraging people to post questions without putting in any effort to show the work they have done.

Comment: Perhaps, thanks for the input. That makes sense, but why down-vote a single answer rather than all the answers involved? I think, doing so does not deter answerers, but it shines a bad light on the answers. I, subjectively speaking, associate a down-voted answer with bad or faulty answer. The answer is correct, even if the question is bad so the question should be downvoted, perhaps even closed, but not the correct answers because it might help someone with a similar question.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost Everyone uses votes differently. If awarding reputation is meant to be encourage behaviors, it stands to reason that the reputation penalty of a downvote could hypothetically also discourage certain behaviors. So in these instances, the purpose isn't so much to leave the answer as having negative votes, but rather to let the person who posted the answer know, through a reputation penalty, that they are doing something that is discouraged (whether this is effective in any way is debatable).

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the input!